# What is a best practice to initialize an object at runtime in a method in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, polymorphism, overriding

I have a java method:

```
public void method(JSONObject jsonRequest, String token, int size) {
    DataRequest request = new DataRequest(size);
    request.from(jsonRequest);

    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(token)) {
        request.setPageToken(token);
    }

    request.doSomething();
}
```

I want to make it a runtime decision on whether to use `DataRequest` or **sub-class** of `DataRequest`. One way to do that is the following:

```
public void method(JSONObject jsonRequest, String token, int size) {
    DataRequest request = buildDataRequest(jsonRequest, token, size);
    request.from(jsonRequest);

    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(token)) {
        request.setPageToken(token);
    }

    request.doSomething();
}

protected DataRequest buildDataRequest(JSONObject jsonRequest, String token, int size) {
    return new DataRequest(size);
}
```

Extracting the logic of creating the `DataRequest` object into another method and let the sub-classes override it.

Is there any better practice to achieve this?

Comment: You should explain about the class hierarchy of whatever class `method` lives in.

Comment: HttpCollector::method(), RestCollectorBasicAuth extends HttpCollector, RestCollectorOAuth extends HttpCollector. Both of these Rest Collectors, read the jsonRequest and prepare their own objects of sub-class of DataRequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a functional `interface` creating the instance like (due to your parameter list you cannot use `Supplier` or `(Bi)Function`):

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface DataRequestFactory {
    DataRequest buildDataRequest(JSONObject jsonRequest, String token, int size);
}
```

Your class provides two constructors (maybe the default factory is not neccessary):

```
public MyClass() {
    this((r, t, s) -> new DataRequest(s));
}

public MyClass(DataRequestFactory factory) {
    this.factory = factory;
}
```

Now you can call `this.factory.buildDataRequest(JSONObject jsonRequest, String token, int size)`.

Comment: what if I make it only one parameter method? i.e. only jsonRequest.

Comment: @JaydeepRanipa then you don't need to specify an own interface but let your class `implements Function<JSONObject, DataRequest>`. Or you can define `interface DataRequestFactory extends Function<JSONObject, DataRequest>` without any further methods as a "named `Function`"